# What is the best way to implement Users & Roles Authorization and Authentication in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

I am looking to see what is the best way to implement asp.net membership in an MVC 3 project. One thing to note is that I have a separate users table and would like to still use this. So can I link my users table to the asp.net memberships table?

Cheers,
Noel.

Comment: There is no such thing as *best way*. There are different ways to achieve this and they have their pros and cons and depending on your exact scenario and requirements you could pick one or another method.

Comment: are you building an intranet or internet application?

Comment: @Lloyd I an building an internet app.

Comment: @Darin Cheers. Just hear some people say not to use the asp.net database and some people say use it. Anyway will look at the pro's and con's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Description

You can implement your own MembershipProvider. Then you have full control about
how authentification works and wich database / tables are relevant.

I think you dont need the default asp.net membership database.

#### More Information

[Create a Custom Membership Provider?](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)

Comment: Yea, have looked at the custom membership provider approach but not sure if I want to go that route. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an additional field (unique identified type) on your custom table and link it to the membership users table.

create new user, if succeed then get id for the newly created user and insert it to your custom table.

```
MembershipUser mUser= Membership.GetUser(username);
Guid myId =  (Guid)mUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

...Insert my/id to your custom table.