# Where should I start in choosing and implementing a ASP.net MVC 3 user/role system?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

There is so much information and terms here I find it hard to start think about users. What options would I have for creating a user-based ASP.net MVC 3 web app? I've read of membership, providers, authorization, authentication, session, cookies, roles and profiles, but I can't seem to get a grasp on the big picture of how user-things are handled.

What are the pros/cons of using a built-in microsoft solution here? What is it even called?
Can I use my own database only (I want to work database first)?

In my mind I think like so: I have users and roles in a database. Users have roles. I want to deny access to some actions depending on if the user is logged in and has a specific role. Am I over-simplifying the issue? Where should I start?

At the moment I'm thinking of doing a 100% home brew system like when I was developing using PHP but since there's so much info I feel like that would not be a good approach here.

Comment: I realize the similarity to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8339910/694325 but I want to know where to start and what are the different options. The question and the answers seem inapropriate for my situation where I have no idea on the direction to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want users and roles, i.e. you want to authenticate users and authorize them with privileges using roles. I would highly recommend not rolling your own, as you would in PHP. Instead, I recommend using the .NET "Provider" services -- specifically, the `MembershipProvider` (for authentication) and the `RoleProvider` (for authorization).

You can still use the Providers with your own db, they are not exclusive to or exclusive with code first. However, I would recommend NOT storing application-specific user information in the Provider's user or member tables. Instead, you can have your own code-first `User`, and link it to the membership system through the user's username.

The reason I recommend this is because it reduces the amount of work you have to do. You need not worry about encrypting or hashing passwords -- the provider does it for you. You have full API to control your users and roles through the `System.Web.Security` namespace.

As for `Profile`s, this is a separate Provider service that you do not need to use. It allows you to store information about users whether or not they have registered for a user account in your system. Technically you can have "anonymous users", but anyone who has created a password-based login is instead referred to as a "member".

Regarding cookies, authentication of a user in .NET is done through the `FormsAuthentication` class. After you have authenticated a user using `System.Web.Security.Membership`, you can call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` to write their authentication cookie. This fully integrates both the `User` and their `Roles` into the `Controller.User` property, which implements the `IPrincipal` interface. You can use this object to get the user's name, and find out which roles they are in.

**Reply to comments**

I [answered a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030427/304832). Basically, it's up to you whether or not to have the membership in a completely separate db than your application, but I consider it good practice, because I have done this quite a bit and I have no complaints. Especially if you are using code first, since you can lose your entire db if you use the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` or `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` initializers.

There is also a new membership provider. I think the NuGet package is called "ASP.NET Universal Providers", and they are in the `System.Web.Providers` namespace instead of the old `System.Web.Security` namespace. I haven't had a chance to work with them yet, but from what I gather, they are more compatible with code first. For one thing, the tables aren't named like `aspnet_Foo`, and there are no views or stored procedures created in the db. The table names are just normal `dbo.Users`, `dbo.Roles`, etc.

As for linking the provider users with your app (content) User entities, see the answer I linked to above. The easiest way to do this is to just have a field in your content db for `UserName`, and link that to the provider db's `UserName`. No foreign keys necessary, since you integrate them at the app-level, not the db level.

Comment: This was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I'll leave the accept open for a while in case of comments and such, but you made things quite a bit clearer for me! On storing user information: are you suggesting that I have a code first user table stored somewhere(?) separate from my content database? Would this mean that the Provider's user table is in 1 database and my "normal" user table in my content database and that they would be linked somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first start with built-in solutions, they're easy to extend if someday you'll need something more (even if to write a **good** providers for authentication isn't really trivial. Start reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme), it's a good start point).

I don't think to write everything here is a good idea, it's a big topic and I should simplify everything too much so I'll post some links I found useful.

Just to start, with text from MSDN:

**Authorization** determines whether an identity should be granted access to a specific resource.

**Authentication** is the process of obtaining identification credentials such as name and password from a user and validating those credentials against some authority.

Imagine **users** and **roles** as Windows users and groups. For example a web-site for forums may have a user named *AUser* with following roles: *User*, *Editor*, *Moderator*. In that web-site they may grant a set of allowed actions: *User* may enter new posts, *Editor* may change posts of other people and *Moderator* may close or delete posts or topics. In this way single web pages don't need to know users but just roles (the `DeletePost` method of `PostController` may be decorated with  `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Moderator")]`).

Start reading [this very introductory article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031204-1.aspx), it provides additional useful links.